# Finding relation of $\alpha_1^2 \xi_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 \xi_2^2 + 2 \alpha_1 \alpha_2(\xi_1 \cdot \xi_2)=0$ for real/complex

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I want to find some nice relation for $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ making
\begin{align}
\alpha_1^2 \xi_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 \xi_2^2 + 2 \alpha_1 \alpha_2(\xi_1 \cdot \xi_2)=0
\end{align}
where $\xi_1, \xi_2$ are vector and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ be scalar (real or complex).

For real case, this is nothing but
\begin{align}
(\alpha_1 \xi_1 + \alpha_2 \xi_2)^2=0
\end{align}

How about complex valued $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ case? Following are answer in some papers I found. I want to show whether equation A.14 or A.15 satisfies A.13 explicitly.

---

[image]

---

I found one answer
\begin{align}
|\xi_1| \alpha_1 = \left[ - \frac{(\xi_1 \cdot \xi_2)}{|\xi_1 ||\xi_2|} + i \sqrt{\Delta} \right] |\xi_2|\alpha_2, \quad \Delta = 1 - \frac{(\xi_1 \cdot \xi_2)^2}{\xi_1^2 \xi_2^2} 
\end{align}
but having a problem showing this is indeed true.

Followings are my trials: Naively from $|z_1 z_2| = |z_1 | |z_2|$, the above relation reduce $|\xi_1| |\alpha_1| = |\xi_2| |\alpha_2|$, but it seems this does not enough for showing this.